# Get sequence numbers of combinated list

Tags: python-3.x, combinations

I need to get sequence numbers of combinated list. Here what I wrote:

```
import itertools

my_list = ["a1","a2","a3","a4"]

for i in itertools.combinations(my_list, 2):
    print(i)

output:
('a1', 'a2')
('a1', 'a3')
('a1', 'a4')
('a2', 'a3')
('a2', 'a4')
('a3', 'a4')
```

But I want output like

```
('1', '2')
('1', '3')
('1', '4')
('2', '3')
('2', '4')
('3', '4')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially you need to remove the `'a'` in front of it:

```
import itertools

my_list = ["a1","a2","a3","a4"]

# use only the number as string, discard the 'a'
myListNoA = [x[1] for x in my_list]

for i in itertools.combinations(myListNoA, 2):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
('1', '2')
('1', '3')
('1', '4')
('2', '3')
('2', '4')
('3', '4')
```

---

Edit:

You comment suggests you would fare better using indexes into your original list:

```
import itertools

my_list = ["istanbul","izmir","ankara","samsun"]

# get a combination of index-values into your original list
combin =list( itertools.combinations(range(len(my_list)), 2))
print(combin)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Print combinations using original list data by indexing into it:

```
# print all combinations:
print( "Flights:" )
for a,b in combin: # tuple decomposition  (0,1) -- a=0, b=1 etc.
    print(my_list[a],  my_list[b], sep =" to ")
```

Output:

```
Flights:
istanbul to izmir
istanbul to ankara
istanbul to samsun
izmir to ankara
izmir to samsun
ankara to samsun
```

Comment: Great idea but the values are going to be change in the future like; list is going to be my_list = ["istanbul","izmir","ankara","samsun"]. What am I going to do when it happened?

Comment: Actually I found it whit your help. Thank you !!

Comment: Yes it s great!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to extract the `int` values.

**Ex:**

```
import itertools
import re
my_list = ["a1","a2","a3","a4"]
for i in itertools.combinations(my_list, 2): 
    print(tuple(re.findall("\d+", "-".join(i))))
```

**Output:**

```
('1', '2')
('1', '3')
('1', '4')
('2', '3')
('2', '4')
('3', '4')
```